# how to redirect to different pages if i use two imagebuttons in gridview1 in asp.net (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a asp.net webform i m working in VB ..

I have a gridview with template field status ..i have taken two image button in same template field in Item Templates ...

i want when i click on image button1 i redirect to default.aspx ?

and if i click on Imagebutton2 i redirect to default2.aspx ?

I have did this ... but ...

```
Me.Response.Redirect("Select_seats.aspx?" & "s_no=" & GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(9).Text.ToString & "&" & "journey=" & Label6.Text & "&" & "seater=" & label4.Text & "&" & "sleeper=" & label2.Text & "&" & "service=" & lab5.Text.ToString)
```

The problem with this is :

that the both image button would be redirect to same page .... if i taken this query in gridview select index changed ?

Comment: You should show us your aspx code from the gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with the ASP.Net GridView control, I have often found the following method to be pretty effective.

Given a GridView with the following definition:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdTest">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblParam1" Text="1"></asp:Label>
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ibtnButton1" ImageUrl="test1.jpg" CommandName="firstButton" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex")%>' />
                <br />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblParam2" Text="2"></asp:Label>
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="ibtbButton2" ImageUrl="test2.jpg" CommandName="secondButton" CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You can then use the GridView's `RowCommand` event to determine which button has been clicked. Note the `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` values on the ImageButton. The `CommandName` can be used to distinguish which button was clicked, and the `CommandArgument` can be used to determine row-specific information, such as an identifying value for the row. That information can be added to the `CommandArgument' using`DataBinder.Eval` or similar mechanism.

You can then capture the `RowCommand` event and redirect based on the command name and argument, something like this:

```
Protected Sub grdTest_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles grdTest.RowCommand
    Dim arg As String = e.CommandArgument
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = Nothing
    If Integer.TryParse(arg, rowIndex) Then
        If e.CommandName = "firstButton" Then
            Dim lblParm As Label = grdTest.Rows(rowIndex).FindControl("lblParam1")
            If lblParm IsNot Nothing Then
                Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?parm=" & lblParm.Text, False)
            End If
        ElseIf e.CommandName = "secondButton" Then
            Dim lblParm As Label = grdTest.Rows(rowIndex).FindControl("lblParam2")
            If lblParm IsNot Nothing Then
                Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx?parm=" & lblParm.Text, False)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

I modified the example code to retrieve control values within the row, based on the questions in your comments. I made the command argument for each button the row index within the table. This will enable you to retrieve controls within that row inside of the 'RowCommand' event using the name of the control.

Comment: i want to redirect to this page using that query :

Comment: Me.Response.Redirect("Select_seats.aspx?" & "s_no=" & GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(9).Text.ToString & "&" & "journey=" & Label6.Text & "&" & "seater=" & label4.Text & "&" & "sleeper=" & label2.Text & "&" & "service=" & lab5.Text.ToString)